# passing scope in $state.go

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I've been working on the routing in my application. I have certain data I can work with, but in the end I need someone to click the button and then go to a certain link. This link information is stored in $scope.stories.link

$scope.stories.link = beautyandthebeast.html

```
  <div ng-repeat="stories in lowage">
<ion-list class="ion-list">
  <ion-item href="#/app/{{stories.link}}" >
    {{stories.title}}
  </ion-item>
</div>
```

Sadly, this doesn't work. Does anyone have a idea how to make this work?

Comment: What is not working the link or the ng-repeat part?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: I am sorry. It is indeed that the Href='#/app/{{stories.link}}' doesn't work. the ng-repeat works, yet the clickable link doesn't. It doesn't want to take the {{stories.link}}

Comment: Okay, so why do you need to have a static html page for every story? Are the story pages within your app or is it an external link?
What you need is a state with a parameter. You can pass the parameter through the link and fetch the story according on the next state.
`https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing`

Comment: That would indeed be the next step. It is kinda confussing for me at the moment. I am building it up slowly. Currently the stories are html files on the server. but I also have them now delivered to me via $http.get . This includes the text. Now I'll be looking into passing parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with this solution it may work for you

In your Html page update the code as

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="stories in lowage">
        <ion-item ng-click="changeRoute(stories)">
          {{stories.title}}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
```

and in your controller write the code as

```
 $scope.changeRoute = function(stories){
   $location.url('app/'+stories.link);
  }
```

Don't forget to inject $location as dependency

OR

you can use this way also

```
<ion-list ng-repeat="stories in lowage">
   <ion-item ng-href='app/{{stores.link}}'>
     {{stories.title}}
   </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

Comment: Thank you for your elaborate response. It is really appreciated :)

Comment: Thanks for your warm reply, can you please accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but I think the problem is that the variable isn't inserted into the code. Your program is trying to go to #/app/{{stories.link}} as it just sees it like a string. You have to use [ngHref](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref).